# How to use sequelize associations generated by sequelize auto

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli, sequelize-auto

I have something like this in init-models.js

```
USERS.belongsTo(ROLES, { as: "user_role_ROLE", foreignKey: "user_role"});
  ROLES.hasMany(USERS, { as: "USERs", foreignKey: "user_role"});
```

If I directly use them in resolver it throws me an error called "You have used the alias in two separate associations. Aliased associations must have unique aliases"

so how to use them in resolver files.

Answer (score 1):

In your `role.js` model, keep the associations in the bottom of the file before the `module.exports`.

```
ROLES.hasMany(USERS, { as: "users", foreignKey: "user_role" }); // OR foreignKey: "role_id"
USERS.belongsTo(ROLES, { as: "role", foreignKey: "user_role" }); // OR foreignKey: "role_id"
```

I hope this help.